# Transparent Bar Chart Excel 2016

Tags: excel

I would like to make a stacked transparent chart like this in Excel 2016.

I cannot find the "format data series" option that this person is using.

http://excelgraphs.blogspot.ca/2013/03/overlayed-multiple-histograms.html

Can anyone please offer some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You must select one of the `series` on chart, `right click` and on the bottom of `dropdown` menu you have `Format Data Series` .

Comment: Thank you.  I am using Excel 2016, but when I right click on a chart, I do not have the "format data series" option.  Is this an add-in?  Are there any other ways of finding the "format series option"?

Comment: When you click on chart, click again on specific bars inside that chart, then right click.